# Server Error in '/' Application in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been having a Server Error in '/' Application when im running my website. I have already tried troubleshooting the problem but i still can't figure out where the error is coming from. It states that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Before this happens, I created a code where if the admin wants to create a new brand, it will automatically write new piece of code on files that i target it to. And also if the admin wants to delete the brand, it will remove all the new code that i wrote previously.

Everything worked fine yesterday but visual studio is prompting me that there are changes made on files outside of IDE and it kept on checking for consistent lines on my code. I just clicked yes to all to update the code. But i want it to automatically reload the files so i went to Tools-Options-Documents-then i checked Reload modified files unless there are unsaved changes. After that, i can still run my website and create new brands but whenever i try to remove the brand, it is giving me this server error in '/' application.

Here is the full description of the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio    2015\WebSites\MusicStore\App_Code\ConnectionClassGuitarItems.cs' because it is    being used by another process.

 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the   current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\App_Code\ConnectionClassGuitarItems.cs' because it is being used by another process.

 Source Error: 


 Line 184:            }
 Line 185:
 Line 186:               System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\App_Code\ConnectionClassGuitarItems.cs", result);
 Line 187:        }
 Line 188:    }

 Source File: c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx.cs    Line: 186 

 Stack Trace: 


 [IOException: The process cannot access the file '    C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio   2015\WebSites\MusicStore\App_Code\ConnectionClassGuitarItems.cs' because it is    being used by another process.]
  System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +216
  System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,    Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions   options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy,   Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1326
  System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean   bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +66
      System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean   checkHost) +73
      System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding  encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) +73
     System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost) +64
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents) +43
   Pages_OverviewData.RemoveConnectionClassGuitarItems(String name) in c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx.cs:186
   Pages_OverviewData.GuitarBrandsGridViewBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx.cs:73
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9696694
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639

  Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET     Version:4.6.1055.0
```

Here is also the code that the error is referring to:

```
    protected void RemoveConnectionClassGuitarItems(string name)
    {
    int counter = 0;
    string line;

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\App_Code\ConnectionClassGuitarItems.cs");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("    public static ArrayList GetItems"+name+"(string itemCategory)"))
        {
            break;
        }
        counter += 1;
    }
    file.Close();

    int removeAt = counter;//or any thing you want
    removeAt -= 2;
    int linesToRemove = 44; //or any thing you want
    string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\App_Code\ConnectionClassGuitarItems.cs");
    List<string> arr = s.Split("\n".ToCharArray()).ToList();

    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < linesToRemove; i++)
    {
        arr.RemoveAt(removeAt);
        result = "";
        foreach (string str in arr)
        {
            result += str + "\n";
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\App_Code\ConnectionClassGuitarItems.cs", result); //the exception is pointing here
    }
}
```

Actually i have 3 more methods for removing the piece of code in different file locations. Sometimes, the exception point on one of those. It just so happens that today, the exception pointed out the code that i provided above.

Comment: `StreamReader` implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). You are not properly disposing of the connection. It's not enough to call `.Close()` on it.

Comment: As far as I know the `Close()` method inside calls `Dispose()`, so the problem lies in something else. Try to check if this methods run concurrently, that might be an issue. In that case they try to access the same file at the same time.

Comment: @NamiraJV - actually the four methods that i created are targeting different files from outside.